# what forced function expression to return value in case there are no operators

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner To JS world and I have a question,
according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ar/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), it says that the keyword Function return a function inside an expression and the form looks like:

```
var myFunction = function [name]([param1[, param2[, ..., paramN]]]) {
   statements
};
```

so in the above form, the (=) the equal operator force the whole line of code to be an expression, return a value and assign it, and this is the correct logic, 
my question is that in:

```
console.log(function(){return "someThing"});
```

who force the function keyword to return function expression although there's no expression here, 
and when I read about conole.log in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log), I didn't notice that it converts the statement to an expression, so what forced this the whole line of code to be an expression and so the  `function(){return "someThing"}` will return a function reference?

accept my apologies for being a beginner to JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about `console.log`. It is an expression because it is an argument to a function call. See [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2) which shows that *Arguments* is `(` and `)` around an optional * ArgumentList* which is either `AssignmentExpression` or `ArgumentList , AssignmentExpression` (i.e. one or more **expressions**, separated with comments).

Comment: your answer till now is the best but i want to ask you , why is the answer of  **Laposhasú Acsa** , is also not true? for example , console.log(Object) , so if we passed any value, this will be evaluated inside the console log like, consoleFunc(Object){  object = the passed argument   } so this the statement will be an expression and will be evaluated and executed as an expression because of the = operator

Comment: "why is the answer of Laposhasú Acsa , is also not true?  " — It is true, it just isn't an answer to the question you asked.

Comment: i asked this question because i feel that both of you are true,

Comment: `consoleFunc(Object){ object = the passed argument }` is a syntax error. You can't follow a function call with a `{` character.

Comment: i expected that we have the console log code (which is native code)  , so let us do anther example , function m(obj){return ob;} , if m == console log , so when we pass any expression as parameter in the m function , it will be processed like m(function expression) , m(){the parameter = the argument } so this step will evaluate the expression . why is this logic not correct in your opinion?

Comment: "if m == console log" — That's irrelevent. As I said, what matters is that it is a function call, not that it is console.log

Comment: "so when we pass any expression as parameter in the m function" — All function arguments are expressions … although the expression is evaluated and the resulting value is what gets passed to the function.

Comment: " it will be processed like m(function expression)" — No. Only function expressions are function expressions. Other expressions are not function expressions. All yellow cars are cars. All blue cars are cars. Blue cars are not yellow cars.

Comment: `m(){the parameter = the argument }` is still a syntax error.

Comment: `function m(){
    
}
function s(funExp){
    console.log(funExp);
}
s(m); `  so what haapend is s function ? m as an argument passed to s function , then inside the s function , this happened  functioExp=s;

Comment: The function **declaration** `function m(){ }` creates a function and assigns it to the variable `m` which is created in the current scope. The expression `m` takes the value of that variable (a function). That variable is used to pass that value to `s`. `s` then calls `console.log()` as passes the value of the variable `funExp` (still a function` to it. `console.log` then logs that value, which is a function.

Comment: "`functioExp=s`" — There is no variable called `functioExp`, and the value of `s` is not assigned to anything other than `s` throughout the whole process.

Comment: "The expression m takes the value of that variable (a function) and passes it s" , passes it to s means , the parameter = the argument ,so this is the expression , if it not , so how the value put to the parameter?

Comment: "Expression" — a bit of code (in a particular context)

Comment: "Argument" — an expression that goes between the `(` and `)` that you use to call a function

Comment: "Value" — the result of evaluating an expression

Comment: The argument is an expression which is evaluated to get a value. That value is what is passed to the function.

Comment: `m` is an expression. The value you get when you evaluate `m` is a function.

Comment: Given `x(1 + 3)`: `1 + 3` is an expression, the result of evaluating it is value that is the number 4, the number 4 is a passed to the function x.

Comment: from the moment you answered, i knew that your answer is the correct, and each line you wrote was simple and i understood, but you raised a question in my mind, what happened when we called functions(string value) , how does this string passed argument passed to the function and became available internally without assigning it to something ? wait a moment , can i guess that inside, the string will be available by  arguments[0]=the passed argument where the arguments is the object of the function within itsscope?

Comment: "without assigning it to something" — It will be assigned to something. It will be assigned to the arguments object. If the function definition declared parameters, then it will also be assigned to the first variable named there.

Comment: I want to say thank you for your time, I am appreciating your patience, your referenced and your well technical wrote answers.Thank You Senior <3

Answer (score -1):

Console.log has parameters, which will be variables inside its function body

```
console.log(obj1 [, obj2, ..., objN]);
```

When you call

```
console.log(function(){return "someThing"});
```

you *assign* `function(){return "someThing"}` to `console.log`'s first parameter variable.

Comment: Quentin, how this does not answer the question:
" so what forced this the whole line of code to be an expression and so the  function(){return "someThing"} will return a function reference?"

Answer (score -2):

Starting from the basic, a function in JS is an Object.

When you use the assignment operator, you are returning the Object created by defining that function.

```
var thisIsAnObjectFunction = function(){return "someThing"};
// to get the "someThing" string you need to call the function
thisIsAnObjectFunction();
-> "someThing"
```

Each Object in JS has a form of serialization, coming from the original `Object` prototype, which is encoded in the `toString()` function.

This means that when you use an operation that expects a `string` as input and you pass an Object, the Object will be serialized calling the `toString()`.

```
console.log( [string1[, string2[, ..., stringN]]] );
```

The `console.log` function expects strings as input, otherwise it tries to cast any input to its string form.

What happens in your code is that you are effectively passing this `thisIsAnObjectFunction` variable to the `console.log` function, hence it tries to serialize it:

```
console.log(thisIsAnObjectFunction);
```

What you probably want to do instead is probably print the result of the execution of the function:

```
console.log( thisIsAnObjectFunction() );
```

Or without using the artificial variable I created:

```
// note the round brackets at the end of the function statement that execute the function straight after its definition
console.log( function(){return "someThing"}() );
```